# Stator wiring in Robin RGD351 not matching manual

Tags: wiring, generator, stator

I am currently trying to figure out why a Robin RGD351 single phase, self exciting has stopped producing power. I have gotten the manual (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/988411/Robin-Rgd351.html) and did some basic testing. Receptacle and breaker on the panel are fine, also nothing grounded out, rotor is fine, got good values on the slip rings, however I am facing issues identifying the wiring on the stator.

This is what the manual says
[image]

It looks fairly easy, however I am having two issues with it. The first is that I am supposed to test white with red and green, which is ok, but as the picture shows there are 4 leads coming from the stator (in the picture) and so what is testing blue with blue supposed to do? If there are 2 blue wires it would be 5 coming from the stator.

Anyway, the bigger issue I am having is that my stator does not have 4 wires coming for it, but considerably more. I have tried making a photo but it is a bit difficult to do as I am trying to disassemble as little as possible:
[image]

There are 4 wires coming off from the stator going to the control panel, however the wire colors dont match. There are also two wires going to what looks like a bridge rectifier (the two black ones on top) and two more (brown ones on the side) going to the slip rings.

My interpretation of the additional wires would be this:

- The two brown wires are probably not really part of the stator and come from the additional small coil on the flywheel for excitation
- The two black ones going to the rectifier could be for the DC output?

Are my interpretations correct? In that case I think I just have to figure out why I dont have matching wire colors to the manual and what they mean by "blue/blue" testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a lot of cleaning and brake cleaner but eventually I realized some of the brown/orange and black cables are not actually that color.... The two black cables going to the rectifier are actually blue and have a 0.2 Ohm resistance as mentioned in the manual. One of the brown cable is green and the beige/gray one eventually also ended up white. All the resistance values check out.

Conclusion: Bad pictures in the manual, but the values match. But its 6 wires and not 4 like in the picture.